# How to read a temporary data in android

Tags: java, android, temporary-files

I'm trying to create a temporary file in one Activity and read in another, because I can't send it using Intent Bundle, and to do that, I was trying to create this.The problem is, I got stuck on this matter.

I already know how to create a TempFile :

```
try{

        //create a temp file
        File temp = File.createTempFile("tempfile", ".tmp");

    //write it
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp));
        bw.write("This is the temporary file content");
        bw.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    }catch(IOException e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

How to get a TempFilePath :

```
try{

        //create a temp file
        File temp = File.createTempFile("temp-file-name", ".tmp");

        System.out.println("Temp file : " + temp.getAbsolutePath());

    //Get tempropary file path
        String absolutePath = temp.getAbsolutePath();
        String tempFilePath = absolutePath.
            substring(0,absolutePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator));

        System.out.println("Temp file path : " + tempFilePath);

    }catch(IOException e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

And now I want to read the content, I was following [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-temporarily-writing-and-reading-files-to-cache-directory/) tutorial but it doesn't work for me, maybe because I'm trying to read inside of class who doesn't extend of Activity?

Comment: send the path to a file from one activity to another(as usual we do send data), do not create new temp file in second activity

Comment: I know,the second was just a example, the real thing started at `temp.getAbsolutePath();`, now i need to read the content

Answer (score 2):

If you created a temporary file using createTempFile(), here is an example on how to read it back to the memory.

```
// "temp" is what you get from createTempFile().
String path = temp.getPath();

FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(path);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
String buffer;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

while ((buffer = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(buffer);
}

// Use "stringBuilder.toString()" if you want to convert it to String.
```

Note that this works only if the temporary file you created is a text file; if not, you might want to consider something else, such as DataInputStream.